# Is User Action Message and User Greeting Messages impactful if no data shown and to redirect to settings page?

Tags: data, dashboard, intuition

Dashboard statistics with no data and showing 0 values because
On the first login you will see all entries appearing as 0. There are steps to follow to deploy configure the software at first priority to get stats from usage.
What can be the possible way to counter the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly - you're trying to figure out what to show on a dashboard when a user first encounters it - before there is any data.

One solution that works quite well is to present the dashboard with dummy data. Don't forget to make it absolutely clear to the user that it's dummy data and present multiple clues on how the user can start to populate the dashboard with live data.

If there are delays in presentation - such as large segments of the data are populated in batch jobs - this delay needs to be indicated as well.

Comment: Yes exactly 
what can be shown to user instead of empty data.
Thanks for the remarks

Comment: " present multiple clues on how the user can start to populate the dashboard with live data."
THis is helpful

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can we simply give a clue with instruction and an action button to the page where users has to follow steps to configure

Comment: This is only for admin level view but for users we might have to show dummy data ...